# Add image and text together using JavaScript in web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to create some like below: [image]

until now what i achieved is below:
[image]

Means i want to add the Text below every image.

Below is my Code that i am currently using:

**JAVASCRIPT PART**

```
 $.getJSON('api/gallery/today_photo.php', function(data) {
    /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */

$.each(data, function(key, val) {  
        var img = $('<img />', { 
            id: 'img',
            src: val.pic,
            alt: 'image',                                                
            class:"img-thumbnail thumb m-r",
            width:"100", 
            height:"100"
          });

          img.appendTo($('#today_images'));
          document.getElementById("today_images'").innerHTML = "Username";
   });


 });
```

**HTML PART**

```
<div id="today_images"></div>
```

How we can add Text as well like above in the First Picture.
 
Currently i am just appending the images in DIV Tag.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are recycling the ID `img` for your images. IDs must be unique. Instead of directly appending to the DIV, use a unordered list and floated list items. You can then insert images in each list item and its accompanying text.

Comment: **@Terry** any example will be helpful

Comment: You are lacking some information in your question: where do the accompanying text come from? In the JSON, or you have to custom define them?

Comment: **@Terry** its a custom define

Comment: Then you'll need to define an array somewhere, so that when you loop through your JSON, you will inject the correct text for each image.

Comment: **@Terry** actually i want the structure rather then values. values i can put but Structure i going to be a bit tauff. So if you can add a bit code in JavaScript then it will be easy for me to pick up.

Answer (score 2):

You can try some thing like this.

```
 $.getJSON('api/gallery/today_photo.php', function(data) {
       // Making sure we are getting JSON           
       var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

       var markup = ''; 
       $.each(data, function(key, val) {  
          markup += '<img src="'+val.pic+'"><span>Some text</span>';
       });

       $("#today_images").append(markup); // or $("#today_images").html(markup);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with putting the description of the image in a separate element like a `span` and using CSS to align them as you want.

Here is an example that keeps the HTML readable in the JavaScript so you can see what is happening:
https://jsfiddle.net/pqgz8c7w/

js:

```
var data = [
    {"pic" : "http://usercontent1.hubimg.com/3616238_100.jpg", "description" : "Burger"},
    {"pic" : "http://innerself.com/content/images/article_photos/x100/food_cravings.jpg", "description" : "Donut"}
];
var foodImg = '';

$.each(data, function(key, val) { 
          foodImg = '<div class="food_img"><img src="' + val.pic + '" class="img-thumbnail thumb m-r" width="100" height="100"/><span>' + val.description + '</span></div>';

          $('#today_images').append(foodImg);
});
```

basic css:

```
.food_img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```